# Decode/encode base64url with common unix tools

Tags: bash

The common coreutils base64 tool can't encode/decode base64url. The `=` padding is optional in base64url and the last two characters of its alphabet are `-` and `_`.[0][1] What is a simple way to encode and decode base64url using common unix tools?

Context: this question came up while working with JWT (RFC7519).

[0]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table

Answer (score 9):

Self-answering my question for future reference.

```
base64url::encode () { base64 -w0 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '='; }
base64url::decode () { awk '{ if (length($0) % 4 == 3) print $0"="; else if (length($0) % 4 == 2) print $0"=="; else print $0; }' | tr -- '-_' '+/' | base64 -d; }
```

Some tests:

```
$ echo 'he' | base64url::encode
aGUK
$ echo 'aGUK' | base64url::decode
he

$ echo 'hel' | base64url::encode
aGVsCg
$ echo 'aGVsCg' | base64url::decode
hel

$ echo 'hell' | base64url::encode
aGVsbAo
$ echo 'aGVsbAo' | base64url::decode
hell

$ echo 'hello' | base64url::encode
aGVsbG8K
$ echo 'aGVsbG8K' | base64url::decode
hello

$ dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=1M > ./test.bin
1048576+0 records in
1048576+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 3.1961 s, 328 kB/s

$ sha256sum ./test.bin
a9d5268ac338fa273245073e463058d9399221c5a60d8bea6cc20cab601863e6  ./test.bin

$ sha256sum <(base64url::encode < ./test.bin | base64url::decode)
a9d5268ac338fa273245073e463058d9399221c5a60d8bea6cc20cab601863e6  /dev/fd/63
```